# Custom board cutoffs pcb

Tags: pcb, manufacturing, board

I have been playing with the board shape, im planning to send this to OSH spark for manufacturing, however i have doubts about if they can do cutoffs of the boards like this or any other possible form i desire, or should i just stick to square shaped pcbs?

[image]

Comment: Have you tried, you know... asking them?

Comment: well... no i havent

Comment: It would be a very poor fab house that couldn't do simple routing like that. If they can't then they aren't worth using.

Comment: @Majenko-notGoogle - it's true that most fab houses *can* do this, but that doesn't mean that they *will* under a given **pricing/service tier**.  But there have been OSH Park orders with creative routing done, so the answer is probably, if it doesn't interfere with their joining tabs too much.  The exception is that the sharp inside corners near the left side can probably not be produced as drawn, as the milling cutter will have a minimum diameter.

Comment: If you use an inside corner radius that is more like 50mils you'll have a better chance. Outside corners can be sharp.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, OSH Park will do custom board outlines. Just use the `Dimension` layer to draw the outline that you would like. OSH Park will attempt to fulfill your request as long as it is a reasonable(*) geometry.

For example, here's a board I had fabricated recently by OSH Park. I needed rounded cutouts in two of the corners:
[image]

(*)The definition of "reasonable" here can only be defined by the OSH Park people themselves. You'll have to ask them directly if you think your geometry is tricky.